# Default all pages to a HTTP connection except for 4 pages which need to be HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, url-rewriting

I am completely new to .htaccess and rewrite rules and I am struggling. Bascially I am working on a website with thousands of pages, I need all of the pages to be HTTP except for 4 pages which the customer data collection and payment process is collected over.

I know I need something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=(default|new(&.*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, NC]
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: You need to be more specific -- what pages exactly?

Comment: The 4 pages needed to be SSL are:

cart.php
Cart.php
summary.php
control.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that those 4 pages are always served via HTTPS try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(cart|Cart|summary|control)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This rule will ALWAYS redirect these pages to HTTPS if not there already: `example.com/cart.php`, `example.com/Cart.php`, `example.com/summary.php`, `example.com/control.php` (all pages are located in website root, as you can see). If they have different URLs, then adjust the rule accordingly.